# What do I need to look into to turn my mysql database into JSON or XML to parse in my android app?

Tags: php, android, xml, json

I have successfully made contact with the internet and parsed a few documents via android and now I think my next big questions is how do I create the client that will convert my database into JSON files I can parse from my android app? Ive done some digging and I know it probably involves PHP, but I havent been able to find much specific info.

What I am looking for in a answer are any of the following:

1. How difficult/complex is creating server end clients like this useually?
2. Keywords I can research for example something like " you'll need a php server side client do hicky , look into [insert php topics I need to study here]
3. LINKS LINKS LINKS!!!

Comment: If you have access to server, you can just export all your database easily with phpmyadmin and can use any format you like for exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You essentially need a server side application stack that will connect to your mysql database, read out recordsets, and send back HTTP responses that include the JSON payload.

You can do this by simply writing a PHP method that returns the JSON formatted response (this would be fairly easy to get up and running).  However if you are looking for a more robust/longterm solution I would invest the time in developing a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web service.  RESTful services provide a common interface to access data intensive applications.

As for how to do this, you can check out Phil Sturgeon's [blogpost](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/03/video-set-up-a-rest-api-with-codeigniter) here that describes how to setup a RESTful service in the popular PHP framework, [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Also if you are not attached to PHP, I would recommend Ruby on Rails as it is designed out of the box to create RESTful web services.  DHH, one of the creators of the Ruby on Rails framework, helped write the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) on RESTful web services.

Comment: VERY helpful post my mans, Thanks for keeping it laymans terms and not pulling all the heavy developer kung fu jargon out on me. I am not "attached" to php , but I am semi familar with it and considering I am still just getting the hang of java I have been told its best to start in php and then switch to Ruby bc Ruby was built for ppl that already understand php and its problems and it has a bigger learning curve. Am I correct?

Comment: p.s my goal is to create a basic social networking app if that helps or changes ur advice for me.

Comment: Yeah if you are already familiar with PHP I would stick with it.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a web service.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

There are numerous ways to do this in PHP.  You could either hand code it from scratch or use an existing framework such as CodeIgniter, Symphony, CakePHP, Zend, etc, to develop a restful web service.  I happen to use the CodeIgniter rest library by Phil Sturgeon (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) for my own project, however it's up to you what system you use.

There are also a number of resources online that describe how to "create a php web service" from scratch. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/ is just one example.

Comment: Well thats 2 votes for CodeIgniter and this Phil Sturgeon fellow so ill assume thats the right direction to be heading in .